# Tab bar for all activity if we navigte to one more activity in (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity

I wrote a simple Android program with 2 tabs. Tab 1 has a button which will open a new window. But I realized that when opening this new window, the Android tab bar will be hidden.

I'd like to always show the Android tab bar when new activity starts ie show tab bar for all activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Android [Tab Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)? If so, then your activities become children of the TabHost and you have no problem.

If you are displaying your own custom buttons as tabs, then you'll need to display that on both activities. Using an include is a good way to do this. See [Creating Reusable UI Components](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html).